# How to get a token for specific userid and connectionname without turncontext

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am doing some work in background tasks and have userid (that was extracted from activity.from.id) and connectionname available with me.

How do I get the user token from bot service? - turncontext is not available.

Comment: Hello, I presume you are trying to do this through the SDK and not the REST API. Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Yes - trying to do this through SDK - C# SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Bot Framework REST API calls must be authorized, so in addition to the user ID and the connection name you will also need your bot's app credentials. If you have all of these, you can get a user token like this:

```
private async Task<string> GetUserTokenAsync(string userId, string connectionName, AppCredentials appCredentials)
{
    var client = new OAuthClient(new Uri(OAuthClientConfig.OAuthEndpoint), appCredentials);
    var response = await client.UserToken.GetTokenAsync(userId, connectionName);

    return response.Token;
}
```

This is somewhat drawn from code that can be found in [BotFrameworkAdapter.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs), but modified to not need a turn context.

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. On a related note, does the bot framework service call refreshtoken automatically at periodic intervals or does it call when such a call is made?

Comment: I have no idea, and I'm not sure why that internal implementation would be important

Comment: Ok. Would be important because if the bot framework service does not call periodically, then my service should make the token call to bot framework service periodically to keep the token alive.

Comment: There's no need to do that. The token service handles everything for you.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Thanks.