# Bot Framework (.Net): Acquire token manually for an OAuth connection

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

We have a Teams Bot making use of Bot Framework SDK (.Net/version 4). In the Bot Service, we have configured 2 OAuth connections (let's call them "Connection1" and "Connection2").

Connection1 gets the token for Microsoft Graph API while Connection2 gets the token for the Bot application registered in Azure AD.

**Current Setup**

In our current setup, we have implemented a Waterfall dialog with 3 steps:

1. Invoke OAuth prompt for Connection1
2. Invoke OAuth prompt for Connection2
3. Implement some business logic

This setup is kind of working ok but we want to change that.

**Objective**

Our objective is to combine step 1 and 2 and for that I would want to manually acquire the token for "Connection2" but unfortunately I have not been able to do so.

What I have tried so far:

**1. Exchange Token**

I have tried to implement the functionality where we would use the token obtained for "Connection1" and get a token for "Connection2". This is the code I have written:

```
var userTokenClient = stepContext.Context.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
var tokenExchangeRequest = new TokenExchangeRequest()
{
    Token = tokenResponse.Token
};
var resp3 = await userTokenClient.ExchangeTokenAsync(stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id, "Connection2", "msteams", tokenExchangeRequest, cancellationToken);
```

However this is failing with the following error message:

```
Unable to exchange token: (BadArgument) No Token found corresponding to this userId/connectionName
```

**2. Use GetTokenAsync**

Based on the answer provided here - [How to get a token for specific userid and connectionname without turncontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58823736/how-to-get-a-token-for-specific-userid-and-connectionname-without-turncontext), I tried to get the token for connection 2. I do not get any errors but the response is always null. Here's the code for that:

```
OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials("bot-app-id", "bot-app-password")
{
    ChannelAuthTenant = "tenant-id"
});
var response = await oAuthClient.UserToken.GetTokenAsync(stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id, "Connection2", "msteams");
```

I think for this to work, user must have acquired a token for a connection previously.

**3. Use GetAadTokensAsync**

I even tried using `GetAadTokensAsync` but that is failing with `Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'` error message. Here's my code for that:

```
var resp2 = await userTokenClient.GetAadTokensAsync(stepContext.Context.Activity.From.Id, "Connection2", new string[] { "api//bot-app-id" }, "msteams", cancellationToken);
```

---

I am completely out of ideas as to how to manually get a token for an OAuth connection in Bot Service using Bot Framework SDK. Any insights regarding this will be highly appreciated.